React native paper dates DatePickerInput modal customization
I am using developing react native on the web, using react-native-paper-dates to show a DatePickerInput on the website, and am able to customize the colors of the date input - but not the modal date picker that comes out of it.
import { View } from '@gluestack-ui/themed'
import React from 'react'
import { DatePickerInput } from 'react-native-paper-dates'
import { CalendarDate } from 'react-native-paper-dates/lib/typescript/Date/Calendar'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

const DatePicker = ({ amountOfMonths = 3 }: { amountOfMonths?: number }) => {
    const [inputDate, setInputDate] = React.useState<CalendarDate>()
    
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <View>
                <DatePickerInput
                    placeholder="XX/XX/XXXX"
                    placeholderTextColor={appliedColors.inputPlaceholderColor}
                    endYear={new Date().getFullYear() + 1}
                    startWeekOnMonday
                    iconColor={colors.darkCantaloupeGreen}
                    activeOutlineColor={colors.darkCantaloupeGreen}
                    selectionColor={colors.darkCantaloupeGreen}
                    textColor={colors.darkCantaloupeGreen}
                    outlineColor={appliedColors.inputBorderColor}
                    locale="en"
                    value={inputDate}
                    onChange={(d) => setInputDate(d)}
                    inputMode="start"
                    validRange={{
                        startDate: new Date(),
                        endDate: new Date(
                            new Date().setMonth(
                                new Date().getMonth() + amountOfMonths
                            )
                        ),
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    )
}

export default DatePicker

I have tried all props including "...Color" in their names and the theme prop.
Went through all type declarations I could find, nothing works for me.
I acknowledge React native paper dates DatePickerInput customization question exists, but it never got a working answer, and it refers to an android instance.
Is there a way to change the modal "primary" color?
examples of live result:



The only option I could find that actually works, is installing react-native-paper, using their PaperProvider and passing it a theme.

Please click the checkmark beside your answer to mark it as accepted.

You can wrap your DateTimePickerModal with themed PaperProvider :
import { Button, DefaultTheme, PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { DatePickerModal } from 'react-native-paper-dates';

      <PaperProvider
        theme={{
          ...DefaultTheme,
          roundness: 2,
          colors: {
            ...DefaultTheme.colors,
            primary: "green",
            onSurface: "orange",
            surfaceVariant: "blue",
            // ...other color declarations
    
    
          },
        }}>
        <DatePickerModal
          animationType="slide"
          calendarIcon={'calendar'}
          editIcon={'keyboard'}
          saveLabel="KAYDET"
          locale="tr"
          visible={visibleDatePicker}
          placeholder="_ _ . _ _ . _ _ _ _"
          endYear={new Date().getFullYear() + 1}
          label={label}
          mode="single"
          // onChange={handleDateChange}
          startWeekOnMonday={true}
          onDismiss={() => setVisibleDatePicker(false)}
          date={value}
          onConfirm={handleDateChange}
          presentationStyle="pageSheet"
        />
      </PaperProvider>

This code above works perfectly if you want to change the default colors (including 'primary') of color of  DatePickerModal from 'react-native-paper-dates';
